# kubernetes to openshift equivalent command

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

In kubernetes I have a command as

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=ewoutp/docker-nginx-curl -n web
```

What should I run if I want to create this inside openshift cluster

I tried this

```
oc create deployment nginx --image=ewoutp/docker-nginx-curl -n web
```

I am getting error as error:

> no matches for extensions/, Kind=Deployment

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It might indicate that your openshift cluster is not running. Check `oc status` to view status of your current project. If it is not running you should create new project.

If you cluster is running you can run `oc create deployment nginx --image=ewoutp/docker-nginx-curl -n web -o yaml` to verify if `apiVersion` is correct. Currently used version is `apps/v1`. If it is incorrect you can save it to  file and edit to match current version.